# Content area height 100% taking the header into account

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fill the length of the screen but my content area of 100% height ignores the header which then makes the area too long. The other SO solutions would not completely work.

I need to be able to adjust for growing content (with the scroll bar on the page not the #mainView), and when there is not enough content to fill the page, the #mainView should fill the screen (with no scrolling).

http://jsfiddle.net/SsF8S/6/

CSS:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; }
#container{margin:20px;height:100%}
#header { height: 80px; background: pink; }
#mainView { height: 100%; background: red; box-sizing: border-box; border:solid 4px pink;border-top:none; }
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="header">
     --Header
   </div>
   <div id="mainView">
     --Main
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry what is the issue. you want your content to overlap the header?

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

Let the header overlay the main view, and pad the top of the main view to avoid it:

```
#header {
  height:80px;
  background:black;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
}

#mainView { 
  height:100%; 
  background:red;
  padding-top: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Updated jsFiddle with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/upQpj/

Comment: This doesn't allow for growing content to be added... Look what happens when I do that with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/upQpj/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should use **box-sizing**:
See http://jsfiddle.net/SsF8S/4/

**CSS**

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: black;
    z-index: 1;
}
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 80px 0 0 0;
    background: red;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mainView {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="header">
    --Header
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mainView">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution also doesn't adjust for growing content as required by the poster...

Comment: Well, it's a minor adjustment. I updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: It's now fixe, the scroll bar won't go below the header by adding an extra div.

Comment: I don't want the content area to be scrollable. I want the whole page to scroll.

Comment: In this case, see V1 (http://jsfiddle.net/SsF8S/1/), before the modifications suggestions :)

Comment: No Pluto was right, V1 will not work because it does not expand with the content.

Answer (score 1):

A few small changes to your mainView's CSS...

Make it `absolute`, setting the `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` properties. Then just remove the old height and change the overflow to add a scroll bar when needed.

```
#mainView {
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

And a jFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SsF8S/2/

Comment: Same issue as Simon. I don't want the header fixed. I want the whole page to scroll.

Comment: So when you scroll, do you want the body's background to display or the div's background? Maybe you can just do this... http://jsfiddle.net/SsF8S/7/

Comment: Nope, if you check my updated code, I would like to add styling to my #mainView that this approach just wouldn't let me do

Answer (score 0):

You could have a main container.

```
<style type="text/css">

html,body{height:100%;margin:0px;}
#header{height:80px;background:black;}
#container{height:100%; background:red;}

</style>

<div id="container">
<div id="header">
  --Header
</div>
<div id="mainView">
  --Main
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the main area to go the height of the screen, not a container

Comment: What is the problem with this solution? The output seems to reflect what you want.

Comment: no, you colored a container trying to hide the fact that the mainView doesn't expand. The yellow box in this fiddle needs to expand the height of the screen. http://jsfiddle.net/WGdJX/